# PHP Requests Being Blocked After Making About 25 in Ten Minutes

Tags: linux, security, debian, php

We have an administrative portal where we run PHP functions through a JavaScript portal using Ajax for administrative purposes.

For example, we might have a function called `updateAllDatabaseEntries()` which would call AJAX functions in rapid succession, with those functions each executing numerous SQL queries.

The problem is after making several successive requests from the same computer (not an excessive amount, maybe 30 in ten minutes) the system will stop responding to any PHP, HTTP requests ETC ONLY from my computer. From other computers in the office the panel can still be accessed, and access is restored to this computer after about 15 minutes.

We believe this is not a glitch but some kind of security feature built into our server, possibly relating to Suhosin and likely well-intentioned but currently preventing us from running our system administration.

**Server Info:**
Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 00:01:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Sounds just like session locking, which is typical for PHP. If you've got a long running process that needs your session, it won't be released until its complete.

Have you looked at the output of `top` on the server when you are locked out, to see if there is a corresponding running PHP process? If so, have you tried restarting PHP, this isn't the solution, but in doing so, you'll notice the session is no longer 'locked'.The same usually applies if you clear the domain cookies on your browser.

If this is the issue, then you should be able to use another browser on the same PC and that should work, despite the other being locked.

Comment: this sounds quite close to the problem I'm experiencing, are there any known fixes to this issue?

Comment: 1. Use a different PC or browser. or 2. Flush your cookies. or 3. Don't use sessions.

Comment: How can I disable sessions for the whole server if I have administrative privelages?

Comment: Don't call `session_start()` ?